# LESSCSS: Assign a value to a property taken from another one's

Tags: less

In some cases is common to use same values in different properties, for example (is just an example to show purpose) the following nested rule:

```
.button-link
{
   height:40px;

   a
   {
     line-height:40px;
   }
}
```

The idea is that to vertically center button text `line-height` and `height` should be equal.

Is there a way in LESS to "*assign a value taken from a diffent property*"?

I know that I should use a `LESS @variable` but in this case is not the same thing and need extra code. Instead should very interesting and useful if I should edit only button's height and then LESS will replaced the same value to `line-height`

UPDATE:
Another example could be the following:

```
.button-link
{
   color:white;
   background:black;

   &:hover
   {
     color:black;
     background:white;
   }
}
```

In which "hover" status should invert `color` and `background-color` comparing to default state.

Comment: In short, no, there's no such feature. Obviously, "property value is a variable too!" idea is flying around but so far it seems like no worth use-cases were found (for this particular example the "extra code" is just one line so nobody bothers :)

Comment: Imagine that I could have many different block like one suggested, each with different values. Everytime could be useful if there would be a strategy to simply having automatic replacement for each one. I added a new example to my question in order to more underline utility ;-)

Comment: Your new example is a bit odd too since it can be simplified to [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cc96ea3b6bbd6c7631a7#file-24282693-less) :) (not counting that `hover` state inherits all the properties by default...) Either way I'm not the one to convince this feature for, I actually sympathise it. But given its possible applications I can understand why it has probably lowest priority among Less contributors. In most cases you just declare a variable (+ one extra line) or a mixin (if you have a long list of such variables) and viola: problem does not exist :)

Comment: Mhmmmm you example is not the same as mine..... you set default state and :hover state to the same values, while I'm setting "INVERTED" values between each one :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry, yep I've overlooked that. Still higher level things like mixins win this fight in the long run (obviously as soon as you have two such classes [a mixin approach](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/ceb9b792e99ae3d5496a#file-24282693-2-less) becomes more compact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible starting with v3 of LESS! [Here is the documentation on it.](https://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties-as-variables-new-)

The example use case they provide ends up with the background-color getting the same value as the color property when compiled:

```
.widget {
  color: #efefef;
  background-color: $color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t :(. What i usually do is:

```
@buttom-height = 100px;
@a-link-height: @buttom-height;
```

and use that variables in your less declarations. Its a dummy example, i know, but imagine calculated data values from other variables or complex dependencies, proportional paddings/margins... that´s the way i learnt from Bootstrap LESS code.

Comment: Thanks kurroman, I already thought about a solution like yours, I only hoped that could be a more "automatic" way :-)